# What might India look like in 2070 in terms of climate change?

Tags: near-future, climate-change

In terms of climate change, what are some reasonable / speculative scenarios for the Indian sub-continent in the general timespan of 2070 - 2100? Hotter patches? Flooded areas?

I am basically looking to build a speculative map of the future for the sake of a story I am writing. I am focusing on India, but informed guesses about the neighbouring regions is also welcome. I understand I am asking for speculation.

Comment: Check out this relevant website: https://www.ipcc.ch/publications_and_data/ar4/wg1/en/spmsspm-projections-of.html

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. When you have time, take the [tour] and visit the [help]. As you might have noticed, we are focused on worldbuilding problems related to fictional worlds, while yours seems more like a (sound) earth science question. Can you clarify the worldbuilding part?

Comment: Hi. Sorry if I did something off-topic. I am looking to create a credible 2100 India for a story I am writing. Hence the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, climate change research is extremely susceptible to politics and opinions. There are so many projections, just choose one that fits your story and make it sound believable.

Comment: @Starpilot even within the same study, there are several scenario: +2 degree or +5degree at two very diferent scenarii..

Comment: No map of the year 2070 is commonly accepted. What you are asking for doesn't exist. But this question still can be saved, just ask if there are any possible changes to the map of India until then regarding flooding and so on, your criteria there. You can then pick what you believe in or what suits your needs the best

Comment: Hello @VijayendraMohanty, and welcome to Worldbuilding. Your question has some merit but unfortunately is **much** too broad to be answered here, and it will be based next to entirely on speculation. We cannot even tell how the world will develop in the upcoming 82 years **whithout** climate change. Your question essentially fails the "Write a book" test: an answer to your question will **easilly** fill an entire book just expositioning how the world has developed in 82 years. So here is the cheap and easy way out: you decide... you are the author, you are building the world.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback all. I have edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: @VijayendraMohanty That edit does not help your question at all. You are asking for something very specific from a process which can take a myriad of different paths from now. This simply is not answerable.

Comment: Sigh. Very well.

Comment: I just want to add that I was looking for a reasonable scenario, much like some of the other questions asked here. I will try asking it in another group. Thank you for all your comments anyway. :)

Comment: I personallt think it would be fine if you droped the most common requirement. Think of it like this: which is the most common wild Elephant in Sweden? It doesn't exist. But i don't speak for all obviously

Comment: The only thing you can be reasonably sure of (most current projections say so) is 80-100 cm sea level rise. But that still gives you a lot of possibilities, and actual developments in the next 60 years may overtake the predictions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which climate change commentator(s) you talk to; [Guy McPherson](https://guymcpherson.com/) will tell you that there won't be anything left alive on Earth to care what India looks like long before 2070. The likes of [Tom Coburn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Coburn) on the other hand will tell you that there is no such thing as climate change and it's a non-issue.

If you want to write about a world damaged by climate change you need to decide on the level of effect you want to convey and then you can use tools like [Calculated Earth](https://calculatedearth.com/index.php) to get an idea of what that will mean in the part of the world you wish to focus on.

Remember melting all existing land and sea ice is going to raise sea-level a maximum of about 66m.

Answer (score 0):

As lots of the other comments have mentioned, no-one knows what an environment subjected to climate change would look like in future years.

Seas rising, higher temperatures, violent storms etc.  There is no "right" answer, so you would need to choose what you think could happen.

Personally, I think one of the biggest changes could be when food and other critical resources start to become scarce and mass civil unrest breaks out.  You could see entire countries fighting amongst themselves for whatever remains of foodstocks.